# Acquiring x y cordinates using bearing and distances

Tags: coordinate-system

A polygon ABCD, I need to find x, y coordinates of points ABCD in WGS 1984.

```
Bearing AB  106.344   Distance AB 497.69m
Bearing BC  182.4108  Distance BC  469.5m
Bearing CD  268.3627  Distance CD 576.17m
Bearing DA  10.5734   Distance DA 636.61
```

Comment: what software are you using?

Comment: This is fairly simple with GIS software with a geodetic function which solves the [forward (aka direct) problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy#Geodetic_problems), though you might not end where you started. Please be sure to take the [Tour], which explains how our "Focused question/Best answer" model operates. Welcome to GIS SE.

Comment: You don't have enough information. What are the coordinates of the first point? Otherwise, you'll have to pick a latitude-longitude location for the first point, and go from there.

Comment: And are they decimal degrees, or possibly dd.mmss (as used in some land survey softwares/calculators)?